# Radiator fan doesnt work!

Tags: toyota, radiator, camry, fan

My Toyota camry altise 2003 automatic transmission car recently had a bad leak with the radiator and replaced it wth a brand new one.Now it drives pretty smooth but I noticed that the radiator fans are not turning on as the temperature gauge reach the halfway through.But when i switch on the A/C fans seem to be working fine.what causes this problem??
When the engine gets completely heated up temperature guage rises little bit greater than half and remains steady as usual.

Its worth mention that im living in  melbourne passing though the winter temperature fluctuates 15-5 Celsius

Comment: I live in a climate where typical summer temperatures are 20 degrees Celsius. I don't remember the radiator fan ever turning on. That doesn't mean there's something wrong with it, though. Let your car idle long enough at standstill when it's 15 degrees Celsius outside. That should do it. Doesn't work for me, though, as my car is a hybrid and thus it doesn't idle.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to solar mike's answer. You could also hook up a scanner and check the sensor reading or just let it sit there and idle, with the ac off. the fans should come on since there will be no air flow(from driving) the engine temp should get hot enough for the fan to come on.

Answer (score 0):

The fans are working as they come on with the A/C. There are two possibilities IMHO, one is that the fans will only come on when the temperature rises sufficiently and that may not be when the gauge is in the "middle" or close to it, as that is "normal" temperature.

If the gauge rises towards 3/4 then the fans may come on as they should - as if the vehicle is not working hard then the temperature stays lower - if you are towing for example the engine can get hotter causing the fans to come on.

Two, it could be the switch for the fan has failed as this is a separate switch to the A/C - this needs to be checked. May be easier to get a new one or to test it yourself you need a multimeter (to check the switch), a thermometer and a pan of water heated to boiling to see when the switch operates at what temperature. As said it may just be easier to fit a new one but depends on the cost...